# Can't connect to MVC Web API from remote server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API that has been deployed to a test and staging server.  It is the only application running on that server.  The API works fine when I access directly from the server it is deployed to but it doesn't work from any remote machine.  I'm not getting a lot of information from Chrome or IE dev tools.  Below is all I see in IE.

http://myapi.com/api/get/related        (Aborted)

In Fiddler I am seeing a 502 - in Chrome I see this

[Fiddler] The socket connection to myapi.com failed. 
ErrorCode: 10061. 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it [ip address]

The things I can tell you about the setup.

1)  The App pool is v4.0 Integrated
2)  Web.config contains

```
 <system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

3)  We are using web.config transforms for each environment.  (This may be a potential cause of the issue if something is missing?)

Comment: Seeing the error "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" makes me think it isn't with your web application. Does your application server have a firewall between it and the public internet, or have any security software installed on the server?

Comment: Thanks,  I have forwarded the issue to our network guys and having them look into the issue.